# Mac OSX : How to password protect an .app or other folder from deleting/moving by user/admin/root

Tags: macos, directory, password-protection

I'm working on a security agent. Wherein I do not want to allow any user/admin/root to delete my security agent application normally.

If user/admin/root try to delete the .app file then OS should show password dialog. If user knows the password then only it should be deleted.

Any pointer on this would be helpful.

Comment: Ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: a remove operation performed by root is not trappable in my opinion, because it's a direct call to the kernel. You need to write a custom filesystem to hook into the remove call, or change stuff into the kernel...not possible at the application layer...

Comment: If the user is logged in as admin/root then it is implied that he knows the password.

Comment: The password I've mentioned here is custom password(not system password) which will be managed by network administrator.

Comment: Do you think Folder Action script will work?